# Cannot allocate memory error in nginx with huge number of redirections

Tags: nginx

I faced with memory allocation error in nginx. I have configured a reverse proxy for a number of sites on my nginx, that I use as a simple load balancer between two backend nodes. Typical config for the site looks like this:

```
upstream backend  {
  ip_hash;
  server <node-ip>;
  server <another-node-ip>;
}

server {
  server_name domain.subdomain.com;    

  # a HUGE bunch of redirection rules 
  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/root;

  location / {

    proxy_pass  http://backend  ;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

I have 12 sites with configuration like above. As you see config contains `include` of another file - `sites-available/root`. This file consists of a number of `unclude` directives to another files:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/rules1;
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/rules2;
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/rules3;
...
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/rules16;
```

Every rules file contains a number of redirection rules like:

```
if ($request_uri ~* ^/some-url$) {
  return 302 /some-another-url/;
}
```

or

```
location ~ some-url {
  return 302 "some-another-url";
}
```

The total count of redirection rules is around 2300. I included `root` file to configurations of all 12 sites. After that time after time I get info message in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

> [info] 23721#23721: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66

The main problem is that sometimes command `service nginx reload` fails with errors in the log:

> [alert] 22164#22164: fork() failed while spawning "worker process" (12: Cannot allocate memory)
>   2018/10/09 03:10:06
>
> [alert] 22164#22164: sendmsg() failed (9: Bad file descriptor)

The issue is gone if I exclude redirection rules from config. Nginx is set up on simple AWS t2.small instance with Ubuntu 16.04. It has 1GB of RAM and I see (with `free -m`) that at least half of the memory is free. I have default nginx.conf. So the question is how to avoid `cannot allocate memory` error, that is caused by the huge number of redirection rules?

This question was originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712936/cannot-allocate-memory-error-in-nginx-with-huge-number-of-redirections). I thought that somebody here can know the answer. Sorry for duplication.

Comment: I don't know about your problem but maybe you can simplify your rules with the use of nginx maps. We have used them to implement jump address for around 1200 domain names.

Comment: I have 12 domain, one for each site. My redirection rules works with request uri within domain. The point is that previously sites had different url structure and important entity identifiers and a number of related systems still use them. I don't know what is nginx map. Can they help in this case?

Comment: That number of redirects sounds like a content management issue - IMHO better to handle content management in your application tier.

Answer (score 0):

Split the file up into smaller parts if it is a large one. I had a 1.8MB file of about 20k redirects which a low memory instance couldn't handle and gave the error you got. I fixed it by:

```
mkdir /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirects
split -l 1000 redirect_file redirect_folder/
```

...and then just including the folder in a server config e.g:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80
    ...
    include conf.d/redirects/*;
    ...
}
```

Nginx then loads fine. I'm guessing but my hunch is that nginx releases the memory used to read a file once it has loaded it, with lots of smaller files the memory use is much lower than that needed to load one big one. As I say though that's a pure hunch, I could be wrong.